# How to initialize form data using async data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

experts!

I make web service using react.

I want to make page to modify user info.

I can receive user data and set data to input's value.

But, react occur warning it.

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. ~~

I think. I did something wrong. when `componentDidMount()`.

I want to know, how to initialize form data using async data.

Sorry about my poor english skill.

This code is part of my code.

```js
export class UpdatedUser {
  @observable private _name: string;
  @observable private _phone: string;
  @observable private _email: string;
  
  // skip setters, getters.
}

interface MyPageComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<{}> {
  global?: GlobalService;
}

interface MyPageComponentState {
  user: UpdatedUser;
}

@inject('global')
@observer
class MyPageComponent extends React.Component<MyPageComponentProps, MyPageComponentState> {
  constructor(props: MyPageComponentProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: new UpdatedUser(),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.global) {
      userService.getUser(this.props.global.loginedInfo.idx + '').subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res.result === 'success') {
          this.setState((prev: MyPageComponentState) => ({
            user: update(prev.user, {$set: {
              name: res.memberInfo.name,
              phone: res.memberInfo.phone,
              email: res.memberInfo.email,
            } as UpdatedUser})
          }));
        } else {
          alert(res.msg);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="user-info" onSubmit={this.updateUser}>
        <h3 className="title">Modify User Info</h3>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" className="form-control" value={this.state.user.name} onChange={this.onChangeInfo} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="phone" className="form-label">phone</label>
          <input type="text" id="phone" className="form-control" value={this.state.user.phone} onChange={this.onChangeInfo} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">email</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" className="form-control" value={this.state.user.email} onChange={this.onChangeInfo} />
        </div>
        <div className="btn-group">
          <button type="submit" className="btn raised primary">수정</button>
          <button className="btn raised secondary" onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack()}>취소</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }

export default MyPageComponent;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey! Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

The warning you get is about **controlled and uncontrolled components**. Basically, you can work with elements such as `input`, `textarea` and `select` having the state in the internal state of a React component or keeping it in the DOM.

In your code, you are keeping the UpdatedUser info in the local state and propagating its data with `value` and `onChange`, so you are *controlling* the inputs. However, where is your onChange callback? It does not exist. Try adding that method to your class and it should work. Take a look at the documentation about [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

The alternative approach is having [uncontrolled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), in which case, you need to pass a `defaultValue` prop to your inputs instead of `value` and `onChange`, like this:

```
    <input
      defaultValue="Bob"
      type="text"
      ref={(input) => this.input = input}
    />
```

If the `updateUser` method gets triggered, you can simply get the new values from your `ref` elements:

```
updateUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('New value: ' + this.input.value)
    this.props.onSubmit(this.input.value)
}
```